# Как передать параметр при отправке запроса на сайт в url

Tags: python, curl, url, requests

Как я могу отправить такой параметр через curl?

[image: вот так я хочу отправить]

Отправка `https://www.example.ua/example?params=вау`не даёт желаемого результата.

Ссылка на сайт с которого хочу получить ответ - `https://www.057.ua/map`

Ответ от сайта должен быть этот текст

> "вул. 15, вулиця Героїв Праці, Московський район, Харків"

Comment: А, если так `curl .............. -d '{"searchWord":"вау"}'`? или если учитывать, что у вас параметры применимы к методу, тогда `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" 'https://www.example.ua/catalogSearch{"searchWord":"вау"}'`

Comment: Русские буквы в URL кодируются https://snipp.ru/handbk/url-code

Comment: Дима, не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

передавайте `Request Payload` в POST запросе как `json=`.

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.057.ua/map/jsonrpc'

r = requests.post(url, json={'jsonrpc': "2.0", 'method': "catalogSearch", 'params': {'searchWord': "продукты"}})
a = r.json()['result']

street = re.findall(r'balloonContent(\":\"(.*\w)\",\"icon\")', a)

s = []
for i in street:
    s.append((re.search(r'(\":\"(.*\w)\",\"icon\")', ''.join(i))).group(2))

n = []
name = re.findall(r'<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>', a)
for i in name:
    n.append(i.replace('<span class="searched">', '').replace(',</span>', '').replace('</span>', ''))

for x, y in zip(n, s):
    print(f'{x}: {y}')

>>> Витамин (Vitamin) кафе-магазин здорового питания : 61000, Харьков, улица Полевая, 83
Беларусь Прадукт, продукты питания из Беларуси оптом и в розницу: 61052, Харьков, улица Карла Маркса, 22
ПРОДУКТЫ маг. ФЛП Котелевец Е. И.: 62203, пгт. Золочев, улица Привокзальная, 2
Пищевые технологии: сушеные продукты пищевые порошки и корма для животных: 61057, Харьков, улица Пушкинская, 20
ПРОДУКТЫ ХМК, маг.: 61120, Харьков, проспект 50-летия ВЛКСМ, 49\/8, 1-й этаж
...
```